# Trying to create a stack calculator in Java

Tags: java, stack, calculator

I have to keep in mind the priority of operations, all the numbers including the answer are integers (seems silly to me but whatever), and I have to parse a String for the equation and, as far as I'm aware, push each number and each operator in two different stacks before I compare them.

I don't know how to approach this problem, and right now my main concern is dealing with parentheses. I want to use a recursive method to solve the calculation which would check for parentheses and solve them and replace them with their result, but I'm not sure how to do that. I could use `substring()` and `indexOf()` but I'd rather be more elegant.

Other than that I'm not sure how to solve the calculation once numbers and operators are stacked. I think I should compare the top 2 operators to make sure that if I combine two numbers, it is in the right order of operations, but I don't want to be clumsy with that part either.

Comment: If this is homework please tag you question as such.

Comment: What do you mean with a "stack calculator"? A calculator that takes it's input in postfix notation (aka reverse Polish notation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be that you study the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and come back when you have specific questions about how it works or how to implement certain parts of it.